# How to batch convert PostScript files to PNGs via folder action with use of ImageMagick

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick, postscript, automator

I'm trying to assign a folder action to the a folder with PS files that would automatically convert the PS files droppped in the folder to the PNG files. My shell script looks like follow:

```
for img in "$@"; do
    filename = ${img%.*}
    convert "$img" -background white -flatten "$filename.png"
done
```

and settings for my Automator folder action are provided in the screenshot below

[image: Automator screenshot]

I'm experiencing two problems:

- When I drop *.ps files onto the folder the Automator action starts but does not produce files. I'm guessing the the problem is concerned with not passing the file name to the *Shell Script* but I'm not able to find solution to this.
- When I attempt to execute the conversion directly from the terminal with use of the command: `convert b.ps b.png` the produced image is cut, like in the screenshot below
  [image: Cut image after conversion].

I would like to fix so the Automator action:
 - Takes all the files that I decide to specify via the *Filter Finder Items* option
 - Converts them to high resolution, quality PNGs respecting the original PS file sizes (without cutting them or providing extra margins)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(You should spell out clearly in your question, that you are working on Mac OSX.)</sub>

---

You may have encountered a bug in ImageMagick when it comes to converting PS files (see also **[this discussion](http://www.imagemagick.com/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26536&sid=5f4c416c43c11e2e5f6d0d3a6a2bdb6b#p116883)** in the IM forum about it). Try to add `-verbose` to your `convert` command to see what exactly goes on.

Fact is, that ImageMagick cannot by itself consume PostScript (or PDF) input. It has to employ a *delegate* to do that for you -- and that delegate usually is Ghostscript.

It's a better approach for your task if you made your shell script differentiate between different input types: if you get PS or PDF, let Ghostscript do the job directly:

```
gs                     \
 -o output.png         \
 -sDEVICE=pngalpha     \
 -dAlignToPixels=0     \
 -dGridFitTT=2         \
 -dTextAlphaBits=4     \
 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
 -r72x72               \
  input.ps-or-pdf
```

Should you need further post-processing of the generated `output.png` (such as making the background `white` instead of `transparent` you could pipe the output to an ImageMagick `convert`-command now....

---

#### Update

Since it has been asked in a comment: if you want to use the same filename for output, but replace the `.ps` suffix by a `.png` suffix, use this Bashism:

```
inputfilename=../somedir/somefile.ps

gs                             \
  -o ${inputfilename/.ps/.png} \
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha            \
  -dAlignToPixels=0            \
  -dGridFitTT=2                \
  -dTextAlphaBits=4            \
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4        \
  -r72x72                      \
   ${inputfilename}
```

or this one

```
 -o $(dirname ${inputfilename})/$(basename ${inputfilename}).png
```

Both will allow you to keep the original directory (in case your 'inputfilename' includes an absolute or relative path). The first one is not as flexible with the input file's suffix: it works only for `.ps` -- for PDF you'd get a `.pdf.png` suffix...

#### Update 2

First determine which is the *real* BoundingBox covered by the original PostScript. This is different from the *declared* BoundingBox, that may (or may not!) be stated in a `%%BoundingBox` line of the PostScript code. Ghostscript's `-sDEVICE=bbox` will do that for you:

```
 gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=bbox a.ps

   %%BoundingBox: 102 118 866 698
   %%HiResBoundingBox: 102.257997 118.502434 865.278747 697.013979
```

Now you can use this info to determine how many pixels horizontally and how many pixels vertically you want the PNG output file to be sized. I'll pick 940 pixels wide and 760 pixels high (to allow for some margin around the output. Use `-g940x760` with Ghostscript to set this as the page size:

```
inputfilename=a.ps

gs                             \
  -o ${inputfilename/.ps/.png} \
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha            \
  -dAlignToPixels=0            \
  -dGridFitTT=2                \
  -dTextAlphaBits=4            \
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4        \
  -g940x760                    \
   ${inputfilename}
```

The output is here:

[image: 940x760 pixels PNG created from PS input]

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments and the useful link. I think I can live with the gs-based solution. I wanted to ask, how can I change the `output.png` to the original file name with the PNG extension? Sorry for not mentioning Mac OS X in my post, I was convinced that screenshots and the "automator" tag will be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the useful suggestions. I tried the provided code but it returned error. `(...) Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: @Konrad: this is not the full error message. The most important one very likely would say: **`Error: ....`** What does this line say for you? Can you paste the full message somewhere in a public *Pastebin*?

Comment: @Konrad: Maybe my instruction wasn't clear enough, and led you to make a mistake. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: @Konrad: Sorry, I had a stupid mistake in my example. It should have been `dirname`, ***not*** `basedir`. Corrected above!

Comment: Hi Kurt, thank you very much for your continued interest in my modest problem. The code worked but the produced image is still cut (and looks like the one provided in the original screenshot). On the other matter, which is quite important to me, assuming that I get the `gs` command to work as it should, how can I connect it to the Automator action? In particular, I particular I would like to know how can I pass the item from the _Filter Finder Items_ to the script?

Comment: @Konrad: Can you provide a link to this funny PS that gets crop when converted to PNG, so I can analyse it a bit more deeply? You should first try to add some variations of a "page size", given in pixels to the `gs` command. The syntax is `-g842x595` (for A4 landscape).

Comment: @Konrad: Run this command to convert it to PDF: `gs -o a.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g9660x8000 a.ps`. The problem with the PS file is that it does not state its `BoundingBox`. So Ghostscript uses a default page size. Which is too small to render all the content. To see the *real* bounding box of these pixels which would leave marks on the page, run this Ghostscript command: `gs -o - -sDEVICE=bbox a.ps` (I used the latter to determin a sensible page size, given in the first command as `-g9660x8000`). Now you can use the PDF to convert to PNG, if you want...

Comment: @Konrad: What's more: this PS is really crappy as far as its formal structure is concerned. Its first line claims compliance with the Adobe PostScript **`Document Structuring Conventions v.2.0`**-Norm (***NOT*** with **`PostScript Level 2`** as many PS amateur programmers would think when they read it) -- but of course, it's far from fulfilling DSC-2.0!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The PS is generated by [Stata](http://www.stata.com/). It's the best way of getting quality images for publications as implemented export to PNG has very poor anti-aliasing so it's either PS => GS or massive TIFFs (which also look poorly). Either way there is an opportunity to pass some rudimentary settings to the way the PS is derived, in Stata it looks like that: `// Set options for PostScript export
graph set ps pagesize custom
graph set ps pagewidth 5
graph set ps pageheight 4
graph set ps tmargin 0
graph set ps lmargin 0
graph set ps fontface Helvetica`